# Not able to flash MCU because of external watchdog

Tags: microcontroller, programming, flash, reset, watchdog

I am using the TPS3813K33MDBVREP watchdog on a PCB with a STM32 MCU. It is connected like the example in the datasheet.
[image: circuit of datasheet]
I can't program the MCU with a debug cable because the MCU gets reset from the watchdog continually. Is there common practice to get rid of this?

I was thinking of putting a jumper in the reset line because I also need to disable the watchdog during debugging. Anyhow, I don't think it is a good solution because maybe I will forget to put it back.

Thanks

Comment: "gets rested"? Did you mean "reset"?

Comment: Maybe you can somehow use the presence of the debug/ICSP connector to disable the watchdog timer.

Comment: Have you checked the documentation for your programmer ? In some cases the programmer also needs access to the reset line and has a push-pull output, so if you isolate the reset line between the watchdog IC and the µC with a resistor the programmer can take full control (?)...

Comment: Perhaps a possible hack: can you use one of the debug cable signals to drive WDI? Make sure that its edges meet the watchdog's requirements.